# Remove / Hide Attachment Display Settings in Add Media popup / dialog

Tags: filters

I would like to filter out the 'Alignment' and 'Link to' options for Inserting Images.

Ideally with php in the functions.php file.

Thanks!

[image: settings are on bottom right]

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried?

Comment: The question seems clear, he wants to hide/filter the 'Alignment' and 'Link to' options